# keras classifier wrong evaluation while learning is great

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

have small dataset

Found 1836 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 986 images belonging to 2 classes.

standard architecture of model

```py
image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        validation_split=0.35
    )
    train_data_gen = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
        directory=directory,
        target_size=(IMG_SHAPE, IMG_SHAPE),
        subset='training',
    )
    val_data_gen = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
        directory=directory,
        target_size=(IMG_SHAPE, IMG_SHAPE),
        subset='validation',
    )

---

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
                tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_SHAPE, IMG_SHAPE, 3)),
                tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),

                tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
                tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),

                tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
                tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),

                tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
                tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),

                tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'),
            ])

            model.compile(
                optimizer='adam',
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy']
            )

            BATCH_SIZE = 128
            EPOCHS = 7
           
            total_train, total_val = train_data_gen.samples, val_data_gen.samples

            steps_per_epoch = int(np.ceil(total_train / float(BATCH_SIZE)))
            validation_freq = int(np.ceil(total_val / float(BATCH_SIZE)))

            history = model.fit(
                train_data_gen,
                epochs=EPOCHS,
                steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                validation_data=val_data_gen,
                validation_freq=validation_freq
            )
```

getting perfect metrics

```sh
Epoch 1/7
15/15 [==============================] - 66s 4s/step - loss: 1.0809 - accuracy: 0.4917
Epoch 2/7
15/15 [==============================] - 56s 4s/step - loss: 0.3475 - accuracy: 0.8729
Epoch 3/7
15/15 [==============================] - 60s 4s/step - loss: 0.1113 - accuracy: 0.9583
Epoch 4/7
15/15 [==============================] - 58s 4s/step - loss: 0.1987 - accuracy: 0.9109
Epoch 5/7
15/15 [==============================] - 59s 4s/step - loss: 0.1127 - accuracy: 0.9438
Epoch 6/7
15/15 [==============================] - 60s 4s/step - loss: 0.0429 - accuracy: 0.9854
Epoch 7/7
15/15 [==============================] - 49s 3s/step - loss: 0.0542 - accuracy: 0.9812
```

but after i evaluate it, i get completely biased to first class results

it works only when i run it for 1 epoch, but with a lack of accuracy

eval code

```py
def make_pred(model, labled_dataset, IMG_SHAPE, img_path) -> LabelName:
    def make_image(img_path):
        # img = img_path.resize((IMG_SHAPE, IMG_SHAPE), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(IMG_SHAPE, IMG_SHAPE))
        img = image.img_to_array(img)
        return np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

    pred_id: List[List] = np.argmax(model.predict(make_image(img_path)), axis=1)
    all_labels = list(labled_dataset.class_indices.keys())
    return all_labels[int(pred_id)]
```

what wrong with it?

should i downsize source image before eval it?

Comment: You are not applying the 1/255 rescaling that you told the generator to do in your make_pred code

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy what you mean by applying? -- oh you mean i also should rescale the eval images, ok - that's why i have `def test_data_prep` - i wrote this code a long time ago, and forget already))

Comment: Your model was trained on normalized images, you are not normalizing images inside the make_image code, its just a matter of dividing the pixel values by 255, if you do not do this the model will produce incorrect predictions

Comment: but why it works 90% fine on 1 epoch?

Comment: please show code for labled_dataset. Also you use image.load_img please show import statement for image. Is it from PIL?  My guess is you are not resizing the images you want to predict.

Comment: Ok you imported it from tensorflow so it is a PIL image.

Comment: @GerryP it's not PIL, it's `from keras.preprocessing import image`, therefore i resizing it

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy but how to predict keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- problem was in `validation_freq` which is should be
  `validation_steps` after that we finally getting `val_accuracy`, so
  training starts validating in proper way
- on top of it `IMG_SHAPE` wasn't the same for `ImageDataGenerator` and
  inside the model `input_shape=(IMG_SHAPE, IMG_SHAPE, 3)),`
- using PIL for prediction may helped too, it gives slightly different
  from `keras.preprocessing.image` results

```py
def make_pred_PIL(model, labled_dataset, IMG_SHAPE, img_path) -> LabelName:
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SHAPE, IMG_SHAPE))
    img = np.array(img, dtype=np.float32)
    img = np.reshape(img, (-1, IMG_SHAPE, IMG_SHAPE, 3))

    pred_id: List[List] = np.argmax(model.predict(img), axis=1)
    all_labels = list(labled_dataset.class_indices.keys())
    return all_labels[int(pred_id)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to do two things. One resize the images you wish to predict, then rescale the images as you did for the training images. I also recommend that you set the validation_freq=1 so that you can set how the validation loss and accuracy are trending. This allows you to see how your model is performing relative to over fitting etc.  You can detect if your model is over fitting if the training loss continues to declined but in later epochs your validation loss begins to increase. If you see over fitting add a Dropout layer after your  dense 512 node dense layer. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/dropout/) Prediction accuracy should be close to the validation accuracy for the last epoch. I also recommend you consider using the keras callback ModelCheckpoint. Documentation is [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint) Set it up to monitor validation loss and save the model with the lowest validation loss. Then load the saved model to do predictions. Finally I find it effective to use an adjustable learning rate. The keras callback ReduceLROnPlateau makes this easy to do. Documentation is [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ReduceLROnPlateau) Set it up to monitor validation loss. The callback will automatically reduce the learning rate by a factor (parameter factor) if after (parameter patience) patience number of epochs the validation loss fails to decrease. I use factor=.5 and patience=1. This allows you to use a larger learning rate initially and have it decrease as needed so convergence will be faster. One more thing in your val_data_gen set shuffle=False so the validation images are processed in the same order each time.

Comment: learning process get stuck at the end of epoch if val_dataset too small, so that's why i increasing split amount and lowering validation_freq